# Installing Nsight in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cuda, visual-studio-2013, nsight

I want to install Nsight in Visual Studio 2013 so that I can start working with CUDA. However, as of now, Nvidia has not released a version of Nsight for Visual Studio 2013.

I want to develop in Visual Studio 2013 because I do not have Visual Studio 2012 nor Visual Studio 2010. What are my options? How can I develop CUDA applications in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is CUDA 6.0 Release Candidate that is supposed to support 2013 is now available that was released in Febuary of this year.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

**NOTE**: looks like this release will NOT have support for the VS 2013(VC12) compiler. The next version of the RC. The next CUDA version will have support for the VC12 compiler, with candidate builds being available this summer

Source: 
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/622306/visual-studio-2013-and-nsight/?offset=23

Comment: I went on some forums and they are saying that they do not plan to support VS 2013. Only this RC will be the one to be released. Is this true? 
And when will the actual release version of Nsight come out?

Comment: it looks like from here they are planning on a summer release

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/622306/visual-studio-2013-and-nsight/?offset=23

Comment: I added more info to my answer ... this RC looks like it does support doing somethings (debugging) in 2013 but it does not use the 2013 compiler and there will be another RC release this summer that will do this

Comment: Okay. But there will be release, right? Nsight will support VS 2013 for sure? And in the mean time, can you tell me how to get started with OpenCL in VS 2013?

Comment: All I know is what is on that form

Comment: Nsight 4.0 supports VS2013. 4.0 Release Candidate 2 is available on the NVIDIA developer site.

Comment: In order to develop for OpenCL you can download the OpenCL headers from http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/. You can link against the OpenCL library provided by any of the vendor implementation as on windows this will go to the Khronos OpenCL ICD layer.

Answer (score 1):

[CUDA 6.5 Release Candidate](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cuda-65-rc-toolkit-download) ([Link 2](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit)) and [NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition 4.1 Release Candidate 1](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/nsight-visual-studio-edition-early-access) ([Link 2](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition)) are both released on [NVIDIA Developer site](https://developer.nvidia.com/) now; they both provide VS2013 support. You don't have to have VS2012 installed alongside with VS2013 anymore.

To download CUDA 6.5 RC, you have to be part of NVIDIA's CUDA/GPU Computing Registered Developer Program, and to download Nsight Visual Studio Edition 4.1 RC1, you have to be part of NVIDIA's Graphics/Game Development Registered Developer Program. I don't know why they have different requirements. You can register an account on [NVIDIA Developer site](https://developer.nvidia.com/) and opt-in the programs from your account information, for free. Applications are usually processed within a day.